# Why can't I use '??' operand for System.DBNull value?

Tags: c#, oracle, dbnull

I have an Oracle data table fetching columns that be null. So I figure to keep the code nice and simple that I'd use the ?? operand. AlternatePhoneNumber is a string in my C# model.

```
AlternatePhoneNumber = customer.AlternatePhoneNumber ?? ""
```

However, even with that code I still get the error.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
```

I know what the error means but why is ?? not usable on DBNull? Isn't null and DBNull essentially the same?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your `customer` object?

Comment: There is no customer object per say since it's what I have in my dataset. I just use the generated adapter and data table classes provided to fetch my data.

Comment: Then you should change the column's NullValue mode in the designer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `??` operator only applies to actual `null`s.

`null` and `DBNull.Value` are not the same; `DBNull.Value` is simply a placeholder object.

Also, that exception is coming from inside the `AlternatePhoneNumber` property, before your `??` operator executes.  (Your code doesn't have a cast).

If `customer` is a row in a typed dataset, change the column's `NullValue` property in the designer.

Comment: Woah, great answer. Thanks for the in depth answer.

Answer (score 3):

null and DBNull are not the same.  System.DBNull is an actual object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `AlternatePhoneNumber` is a string.  DBNull is not.

Try this instead:

```
AlternatePhoneNumber = (customer.AlternatePhoneNumber as string) ?? ""
```

Comment: The `AlternatePhoneNumber` property is already a string.  This won't help.

Comment: If it's a string, then it can't be a DBNull.

Answer (score 2):

DBNull is a type with a single value, and is not the same as a null string reference, which is why you can't use `??`. You could do this however:

```
string alternativePhoneNumber = DBNull.Value.Equals(customer) ? string.Empty : ((Customer)customer).AlternatePhoneNumber;
```

Comment: This code is wrong on many levels.  `DBNull` is miscapitalized.  You shouldn't bother calling `.Equals`.  `Customer` is neither`DBNull` nor a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
public T IfNull<T>(object o, T value)
{
   return (o == DbNull.Value) ? value : (T)o;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other replies state, `null` means a reference that refers to no object, while `DBNull` is a class supplied by ADO.NET to *indicate* when a field or value is NULL at the database (or in a DataTable).

While you can use the [conditional (ternary) operator (?:)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1(VS.71).aspx) to do what you want:

```
AlternatePhoneNumber = customer.AlternatePhoneNumber is DBNull 
                           ? "" 
                           : customer.AlternatePhoneNumber;
```

I tend to wrap this up in an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
static class NullExtensions
{
    public static T WhenNull<T>( this object value, T whenNullValue )
    {
        return (value == null || value is DBNull)
            ? whenNullValue
            : (T)value;
    }
}
```

which I find makes the code easier to read and understand.

```
AlternatePhoneNumber = customer.AlternatePhoneNumber.WhenNull( "" );
```

Comment: This won't compile.  `AlternatePhoneNumber` is a string.

Comment: @SLaks: Which part won't compile? The extension method accepts an `object` and returns a type that matches the default value.

Comment: `customer.AlternatePhoneNumber is DBNull` won't compile because it's statically typed as `string`.  Your extension method won't help, because the exception is coming from inside the property.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, I see what you're saying. Ye, the OP needs to change the implementation of the property in that case.

Answer (score 1):

DBNull is NOT a real "null".

The "??" - operator detects only null - references, not objects that emulate "null" behavior.